# Editing a 'sidebar' in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

There seems to be a problem with something on my wordpress page as a widget isn't displaying but I'm not sure how to edit the widget.

The code on homepage.php under Appearance>Editor is

```
<section class="row post_content">

  <div class="col-sm-8">

    <?php the_content(); ?>

  </div>

  <?php get_sidebar('sidebar2'); // sidebar 2 ?>

</section> <!-- end article header -->
```

Where would I find the code for 'sidebar2' as at the moment an error message appears on the page where the sidebar should display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As outlined in the Developer handbook for [`get_sidebar()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sidebar/), your sidebar file should be called `sidebar-sidebar2.php`. This file will be present in the root directory of your active theme.

> The `get_sidebar()` hook allows a specific sidebar template file to be used in place of the default sidebar template file. If your file is called sidebar-new.php, you would specify the filename in the hook as get_sidebar( 'new' ).